# Page redirecting Not working in php

Tags: php

Page redirecting Not working when session die showing blank page

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['id']) )
die
 {

header(" Location:http://mysite.in/newlogin.php");
exit();
}
```

plerse any one can help

Comment: `die` is the [equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) of `exit`. I don't think you should be using it the way you are in your code.

Comment: have look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: there's so many things wrong with this code. you can't die & exit, also you have a space in your header (not sure if that matters).

Comment: ok i am beginner in php please help us

Comment: Look at the link RohitS posted, that has your answer.

Comment: If you'd used an IDE (like e.g. Netbeans) you'd have gotten a number of syntax errors highlighted .

Answer (score 0):

- Your code is poorly-designed, buggy and does not make sense.
- Avoid using 'die' on handling errors.
- Read some about Exception Handling techniques on PHP.
- Before reading all the please have some time developing your skill on PHP and programming don't be hurry.
- Actually die and exit doing the "exit" action but with some differences.